# Getting 401 by doing any call to an embedded tomcat inside spring boot inside docker container

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, tomcat, docker-compose

Containers are created from docker-compose 3.9 as following:

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo:4.4.15
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    volumes:
      - mongo-vol:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
    healthcheck:
      test: echo 'db.runCommand("ping").ok' | mongo localhost:27017/test --quiet
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 40s

  mysql:
    image: mysql
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'mydb'
      MYSQL_USER: 'user'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'password'
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'password'
    volumes:
      - mysql-vol:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
    healthcheck:
      test: /usr/bin/mysql mysql -ppassword --silent --execute "select 1"
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5

  my-be:
    image: be_image
    container_name: be-container
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      spring.datasource.url: "jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/mydb?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false&createDatabaseIfNotExist=true"
      datasource.driver-class-name: "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"
      spring.h2.console.enabled: "false"
      spring.jpa.database-platform: "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"
      spring.data.mongodb.host: mongo
      spring.data.mongodb.port: 27017
      logging.file.path: logs
      server.port: 8080
    depends_on:
      mongo:
        condition: service_healthy
      mysql:
        condition: service_healthy
volumes:
  mysql-vol:
  mongo-vol:
```

I'm creating a Backend container, a mysql and a mongo.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:17
EXPOSE 8080
ARG JAR_FILE="target/MyAPP-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"
ADD ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

I create the build image of the BE and I'm using it inside the docker-compose. This is the situation now:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE          COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS                    PORTS                                           NAMES
996da02a43e5   be_image       "java -jar /app.jar"     11 minutes ago   Up 11 minutes             0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp, :::8080->8080/tcp       be-container
9c3d11ceb0ee   mongo:4.4.15   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   11 minutes ago   Up 11 minutes (healthy)   0.0.0.0:27017->27017/tcp, :::27017->27017/tcp   compose-mongo-1
15fe4d52a50e   mysql          "docker-entrypoint.s…"   11 minutes ago   Up 11 minutes (healthy)   3306/tcp, 33060/tcp                             compose-mysql-1
```

I'm using Spring security. So when I try putting localhost:8080, it prompts for user and password. when I input them, everything seems working fine, displaying the usual Whitelabel Error Page.
But, if I try to retrieve the swagger-io, it gives me an empty swagger (while without docker it works fine).
And, if I try to call a POST or any call from POSTMAN (even calling just localhost:8080), it returns 401 unauthorized, without logging anything inside the spring boot app. Last log is

```
2023-03-14T14:11:07.344Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.example.myapp.MyApplication       : Started MyApplication in 3.978 seconds (process running for 4.521)
```

It seems like there's a block just right before reaching tomcat. And if I try to call https instead of http, I actually have a log inside spring boot:

```
 2023-03-14T14:13:36.511Z  INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-03-14T14:13:36.513Z  INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 1 ms
2023-03-14T14:14:02.018Z  INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.springdoc.api.AbstractOpenApiResource  : Init duration for springdoc-openapi is: 99 ms
2023-03-14T14:34:55.564Z  INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor   : Error parsing HTTP request header
 Note: further occurrences of HTTP request parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in method name [0x160x030x010x000xf70x010x000x000xf30x030x03z0xfe0x90q0xe80x0an0x960xd50xcc0xb80x93lv0xfcf0xfc0xf50xdeT0x980xfa0xd6?0x99^0xe70x940x900xcaoP ]. HTTP method names must be tokens
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:419) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:272) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1739) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar!/:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

So seems like something gets logged. I don't understand what I'm missing, I know i'm close to make it work.

Without dockerizing, everything works fine locally

Answer (score 0):

Are you using SSL? If you're trying to hit your endpoints using https but your server doesn't support it you may get an error that looks like this.

Comment: the call with https was just an example of the fact that the application did log something, it is not the main point here